# oscillioscope specification for low speed usb device

Tags: usb, gyroscope

I want to capture the low speed USB device packets, What specification is required for it? I am looking for inexpensive oscilloscope.

As USB low speed device work at 1.5 MBit/s, Is hantek 6022be sufficient for it?

Hantek 6022BE Specification

Bandwidth: 20MHz;

Sample Rate: 250MSa/s

Product page: https://www.amazon.in/HT6022BE20Mhz-Digital-Storage-Oscilloscope-Bandwidth/dp/B009H4AYII

Comment: This is not a product recommendation site. How many users do you think are going to go chasing over the net looking for a 6022be manual? If you expect people to read it, then link to it. Better, summarise the key timebase specifications in your question. Even better, compare those specs to the speed of waveforms you expect to see for USB, and ask if those ratios are adequate.

Comment: If you're looking to capture packets for development of protocols and drivers you'd be better off with a protocol analyser.

Comment: I want to understand software only low speed usb libraries (Vusb, USBTiny) for avr 8 bit micro controller and implement is into another 8 bit mcu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need an oscilloscope at all. What you need is either a logic analyzer (if possible with a USB protocol decoder) or a standalone USB protocol analyzer.

Good thing is that oscilloscopes are rather expensive, whereas a logic analyzer that's fast enough for a meagre 1.5 Mbd/s would actually cost you less than 10$ (FX2 eval boards + sigrok software).

Chances are you don't even need that. With a normal operating system (e.g. Linux) and common software tools (e.g. Wireshark) you can capture USB traffic at the packet level in software if it happens with your computer.